# WSO2 API Manager oAuth2 secret_token validation service problems

Tags: wso2

We have installed WSO2 Api Manager without standalone Identity Server (identity is embedded
). When i try to check oAuth2 user access_token with OAuth2TokenValidationService with curl command:

```
curl --user apivalidatekey:apivalidatekey --header "Content-Type: text/xml" -k -d @soap.xml https://localhost:8243/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService/
```

where soap.xml is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd"
 xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <xsd:validate>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <xsd:validationReqDTO>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd1:accessToken>691e72a68e2f0e0c07a4236c14c485</xsd1:accessToken>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd1:tokenType>bearer</xsd1:tokenType>
     </xsd:validationReqDTO>
  </xsd:validate>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I`v got an error on API Manager host in wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-02-05 14:19:03,945] ERROR {java.lang.Class} -  System failure.null {java.lang.Class}
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.doAuthorization(AuthorizationHandler.java:105)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:404)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:184)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What is the problem, does embedded IS supports such a web service, because i can get a wsdl for it:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService?wsdl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"OAuth2TokenValidationService" is an admin service that is secured. Therefore to invoke this service, you must send the privileged users credentials in Basic authentication header. But It seems to be that you are sending the api key and secret which is not valid. Could you please try to send default admin users credentials (which is "admin" "admin")in basic auth header and see.

> curl --user admin:admin --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --header "SOAPAction: validate" -k -d @soap.xml `https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService/`

Comment: The same error with:
`curl --user admin:admin`
We created new user as an experiment, when using admin:admin fails.
So You say i need to send an api key also?
Where can i configure api key for admin service?

Comment: no you do not need to send the API keys for validate the access token. You only need to use API keys to grant an access token. To validate, you only need to pass the access token..  But "OAuth2TokenValidationService"  is an secured service. Therefore you need to authenticate to access this service (Normally you can use the credentials that you use login to management console)

Comment: Also..  in your curl request... Server's Port is invalid (not 9763). It must be "9443"

Comment: Thank You for your attention and help.  
Does `curl --user admin:admin`  is the only thing to authenticate? admin:admin are active credentials on my management console.  
I check log file and it says that authentication procedure is finished with true. Error is on the authorization phase.  
Using port 9443 returns another error:  
`{org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/OAuth2TokenValidationService/ and the WSA Action = null.`

Comment: Also port 8243 was in the wsdl file for this service.

Comment: I changed a port in initial question, it was 8243.

Comment: You need to use 9443..  Admin service has been exposed via that port.. Issue is the you are not sending the SOAP action in the request..  so you can see above error..  you need to set it using curl --header "SOAPAction: validate"      However, i have updated by curl comment in above comment, Please check it.

Comment: Thank You.  
--header "SOAPAction: validate" made my day! (: